# To what extent are questions allowed to change by nature?

Tags: discussion

If a question is edited in such a way that makes answers to the original question redundant, what is the suggested action for other users who have answered?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I do not. This is more of a curiosity rather than a by-case question

Comment: @Xenyal The issue is a general rule for this doesn't really exist... it should be handled case-by-case.

Comment: @KevinB where should these cases be brought up? I feel case-basis don't justify having a new question being brought up in meta. Also, how does one contact a moderator for discussion in SO Meta chatroom?

Comment: Why does a moderator need to be involved? any user with enough rep to rollback can roll it back *if it needs to be rolled back*. If an edit war begins you can flag it with a custom message to bring it to a moderator's attention.

Comment: Good point, it's clear to me now. I asked the latter because the description in the meta chatroom reminds users to invite a mod before using the room. Didn't really specify how one could do that

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two general situations that cause an edit to invalidate an answer.

1. The answerer simply misunderstood the question.  An edit is clarifying the question to make the authors original intentions clearer, and after the edit other readers can now see that the answer is based on a mis-interpretation of the question.

   In this case the answer is simply a wrong answer.  As the answerer, you should either edit it to reflect the real question, or delete it if you can't.  If you feel that your answer along with what you thought the original question was is information worth keeping around, then ask a new question yourself in which you ask the question you thought was being asked originally (hopefully more clearly), and provide your answer to that question.
2. The answerer really did understand the intent of the author's original question, and the author is editing the question to reflect a fundamentally new question.  Sometimes this is to ask a follow up question based on answers/comments given, sometimes the author realizes that their real problem is radically different than what they thought it was earlier, and sometimes a user is question banned and is just editing an old question because they can't ask a new one.

   In these cases editing the question to be a fundamentally different question, rather than clarifying its original intent, is an inappropriate edit.  You can roll back such an edit (although you should generally comment explaining why here, and encouraging the user to ask their new question as a new question, rather than through an edit).  That said, don't get into a rollback war; if the edit is applied again simply flag and move on, as only a moderator has the tools to appropriately deal with the situation at that point.

   There is no need to edit or delete the answer at this point.